# How to get markers pose in a file?

Tags: ros, rosbag, ar-pose, ar-track-alvar

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi,
I am using different AR tags and need to know how I can save their poses into a text file so I can use their poses in a MATLAB code. When I use "echo", it gives me a long list with different markers_id and the poses are not fixed. Any suggestion?
Thanks

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/149351/how-to-get-markers-pose-in-a-file?/) by [miloup](https://answers.ros.org/users/13906/miloup/) on ROS Answers with karma: 31 on 2014-04-06

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

@ggregory8 is absolutely right with using rosbag.

I also want to mention the solution with plain rosbag.

Record your data with

```
rosbag record /topic
```

And then process it in Matlab with the [matlab_rosbag](https://github.com/bcharrow/matlab_rosbag) package.

---

Originally posted by [BennyRe](https://answers.ros.org/users/3675/bennyre/) with karma: 2949 on 2014-05-27

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1

Answer (score 0):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi,

You can echo straight into a file using:

```
rostopic echo /topic > filename.txt
```

But this isn't ideal as it will be the same format as the echo displays it to the commandline.

A better way is to record topics using rosbag and then you can write the topic data you want straight to a file using:

```
rostopic echo -b file.bag -p /topic > filename.txt
```

This has the benefit of formatting the data suitable for a csv file, which you can then manipulate with excel / matlab.

---

Originally posted by [ggregory8](https://answers.ros.org/users/15261/ggregory8/) with karma: 13 on 2014-05-26

This answer was **NOT ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1